# Optimizing SQL query on table of 10 million rows: neverending query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE routing
 (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  link_geom geometry,
  source integer,
  target integer,
  traveltime_min double precision,
  CONSTRAINT routing_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
  )
  WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
  );

 CREATE INDEX routing_id_idx
    ON routing
    USING btree
    (id);

CREATE INDEX routing_link_geom_gidx
 ON routing
 USING gist
 (link_geom);

CREATE INDEX routing_source_idx
 ON routing
 USING btree
 (source);

CREATE INDEX routing_target_idx
 ON routing
 USING btree
 (target);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
 link_id character varying,
 link_geom geometry,
 id integer NOT NULL,
 .. (some more attributes here)
 traveltime_min double precision,
 CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id),
 CONSTRAINT test_link_id_key UNIQUE (link_id)
  )
 WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
  );
 ALTER TABLE test
 OWNER TO postgres;
```

and I am trying to appy the follwing query:

```
update routing
set  traveltime_min = t2.traveltime_min
from test t2
where t2.id = routing.id
```

Both tables have near 10 millions rows. The problem is that this query runs neverending. Here what 'EXPLAIN' shows:

```
Update on routing  (cost=601725.94..1804772.15 rows=9712264 width=208)
 ->  Hash Join  (cost=601725.94..1804772.15 rows=9712264 width=208)
       Hash Cond: (routing.id = t2.id)"
        ->  Seq Scan on routing  (cost=0.00..366200.23 rows=9798223 width=194)"
        ->  Hash  (cost=423414.64..423414.64 rows=9712264 width=18)"
            ->  Seq Scan on test t2  (cost=0.00..423414.64 rows=9712264 width=18)"
```

I cannot understand what might cause the problem of such a slow response. 
Is it possible to be a problem caused from the server settings? The thing is that i use the default postgrSQL 9.3 settings.

Comment: welcome to SO. If you want some DBA-Advice, maybe its better to ask your question here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/ But you will get some answers here as well, i think

Comment: Maybe your update is waiting for a lock? Did you check that? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop all indexes on `routing` before you run the `UPDATE` and add them again afterwards. That will bring a huge improvement.

Set `work_mem` high in the session where you run the `UPDATE`. That will help with the hash.
Set `shared_buffers` to ¼ of the available memory, but not more than 1GB.

Comment: 'work_mem' = 1024kB and 'shared_buffers' =  16384 as I see from the pg_settings. I am reluctunt of changing the configuration values because in the past it had caused me additive problems. But thank you. I will give it a try.

Comment: Yes, leave those settings. But try without the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

- If not all the rows are actually changed by the UPDATE (if the get the same value as they had) , you should avoid these idempotent updates.
- if you expect the query to affect every row, the query plan is not important. [except, maybe, for the case of overflowing hash tables ...]

---

```
-- these could be needed if the update would be more selective...
VACUUM analyze routing;
VACUUM analyze test;

UPDATE routing dst
SET  traveltime_min = src.traveltime_min
FROM test src
WHERE dst.id = src.id
   -- avoid useless updates and row-versions
AND dst.traveltime_min IS DISTINCT FROM src.traveltime_min
   ;

-- VACUUM analyze routing;
```

Comment: all the rows will be updated. Actually I created a new column in the routing table and I want to pass all the values from the other table, where columns id's are same.

Comment: In that case the DBMS will have to handle 9M rows * 200 bytes. About three times, since both the original page + the new row versions will have to be (re)written. That is about 6GB of disk traffic.